# Unable to open remote display on Mac when running Docker

Tags: macos, docker

I have a Dockerfile written as below:

```
FROM     joesan/raspi_opencv_3:latest
RUN      apt-get update
RUN      sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xserver-xorg
RUN      sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xinit
RUN      apt-get install -qqy x11-apps
RUN      mkdir -p /raspi_motion_detection/project
WORKDIR  /raspi_motion_detection/project
COPY     ./ $WORKDIR/
COPY     ./requirements.txt $WORKDIR/
ADD      . $WORKDIR
CMD      xclock
```

I have a Raspberry Pi to which I ssh from my Mac (running High Sierra).

Here is what I do:

1. I ssh into the RaspPi from my Mac
2. I execute the docker command using:

> ```
> docker run -ti --device=/dev/vcsm \
> --device=/dev/vchiq \
> -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY:0 \
> -e XAUTHORITY=/.Xauthority \
> -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
> joesan/motion_detector
> ```

3. I get an error message as below:

   Error: Can't open display: localhost:11.0:0
4. But when I just run xclock directly on the ssh terminal, I can see that the xclock window opens up.

So I could not understand why running xclock from within a Docker container would prevent the display port being opened? Any reasons? I also came across this post here and followed what has been described there, but i could not get it to work!

https://medium.com/@dimitris.kapanidis/running-gui-apps-in-docker-containers-3bd25efa862a

Comment: Concerning the link: This won't do you any good as that installs xquartz on your mac. But you are trying to launch xclock on your raspberry pi.

Comment: You are correct, but I'm trying to launch xclock on RasPi from my Mac. I use my Mac to SSH into the RasPi and then run the docker image.

Comment: Do you understand what `$DISPLAY` does, and how ssh interacts with it?

Comment: Not fully, but I take it that it is a mechanism to pipe data from one system to another system...

Comment: @sparkr Sorry, but this is not correct. You are trying to launch xclock on your raspberry from docker on your raspberry. As soon as you connect via ssh, you are executing all commands on the raspberry.

Comment: I found the solution and got it to work! It may not be ideal, but it just works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit simplified: Each docker container runs inside the docker daemon, which basically provides a stripped down os to each container. That os has no window manager.

That is why the command `xclock` inside a docker container exits with an error.

When you connect via ssh to your raspberry pi and call `xclock` it is executed inside the raspberry's os (propably raspian), which has a running window manager.

Comment: But I'm installing xserver-xorg in my Docker container. Isn't that enough?

Comment: Your explanation seems reasonable, but what could be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ok! So I thinkI found the solution to my problem! Here is what I did!

1. Re-installed Raspberry Stretch Lite on my SD card. The old one seems to have gotten some stale files! You can skip this step, but for me there was some corrupt files on the old installation, so I decided to get a fresh install!
2. On my Raspberry Pi, run the following command:

   xauth list

   I copy the cookie locally to a text editor as I need it later!
3. Removed the xclock command from the Dockerfile that I originally had!
4. Build the Dockerfile using the following command:

> docker run -it --net=host --device=/dev/vcsm --device=/dev/vchiq -e
>   DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix joesan/motion_detector bash

Notice that I'm running a bash command to my Docker run so that I can get a basj prompt from the running image!

4. The result of step 3 would give me a bash prompt from the container that I just ran at step 3
5. I need to now install xauth in the image

> apt-get install xauth

6. I then add the xauth cookie from step 0

It is after this Bang! I got what I want!